# can't return a generic while create jooq custom mapper

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I want to write a custom mapper that can cast jooq record to map, but hot some problem, Here is my code.

```
public class BaseMapper<R extends Record, E extends Map> implements RecordMapper<R, E> {

@Override
public E map(R record) {
    if (record == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Arrays.stream(record.fields())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Field :: getName,
                    field -> record.get(field),
                    E :: new
            ));
}
```

When I implement the map method of RecordMapper, I don't know how to return a E type instance because you can't instance a generic type.

Answer (score 0):

jOOQ has an out of the box [`Record.intoMap()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#intoMap--) method, which seems to do exactly what you're looking for, so just write this:

```
public class BaseMapper<R extends Record> implements RecordMapper<R, Map<String, Obhect>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> map(R record) {
        return record == null ? null : record.intoMap();
    }
}
```